# Missing Behavior in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, containable

I need your help I'm developing a website using CakePHP in localhost, but when i trying to upload to server i get this error 
Missing Behavior

> ```
> Error: containableBehavior could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class containableBehavior below in file: 
>        app/Model/Behavior/containableBehavior.php
> ```

```
<?php
class containableBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

}
```

Comment: Mind your casing. This is a very important thing when programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi i'm sorry i found the solution for my problem :)

the problem is when i made public $actsAs=array('**containable**'); in my appModel this not work in website the solution is to the first digit uppercase $actsAs=array('**Containable**')
good day :)